# Create a backup file with MongoVUE

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

Is there a way to create a back file of an entire database using MongoVUE?

I can't see anything in the UI to do this

Comment: I just ran into the same issue, would be nice if they add a back option to this GUI!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you can only backup (they call it Export) a collection at a time.

Select a collection to view and then click the drop down arrow to the right of the "Refresh" button at the right of the View display and click Export.

Select the export format (csv, excel etc) and save as required.

I also miss this feature but I think writing an export/backup application will be easy enough that I will try when I have time